# Highcharts skipping second x-axis label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to specify the category index in the series data, but when I do this, the second label seems to be missing. Does anyone know what might be going on? I've tried setting the step already.

```
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            },
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NVV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange.  The only way I can find to force it to display is to explicitly set the `tickPositions`:

```
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
            tickPositions: [0, 1, 2]
        },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NVV/1/).